# Close Stage with Escape button in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I've created the following function in order to close any pop up `Stage` in my program:

```
public void escapeKeyPressed(final KeyEvent keyEvent , Stage diolog) {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            diolog.close();
        }
    }
```

Then, I have a clickable image where can be clicked and a form will pop up :

The problem is when I call the function I get error for the first argument . 
Here is how I call it ;)

```
 escapeKeyPressed( KeyCode.ESCAPE ,dialog );
```

Does any body know how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method signature is `(final KeyEvent keyEvent, Stage diolog)` and you pass a `KeyCode` as first argument which is not a `KeyEvent`.

You can pass the original `KeyEvent` instead, to fulfil the signature as:

```
yourPopUp.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> escapeKeyPressed(event, dialog ));
```

But it would be much cleaner if you would update the method signature to accept the `KeyCode` directly:

```
public void escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode keyCode , Stage diolog) {
    if (keyCode == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
        diolog.close();
}
```

In this case you can have the original call as:

```
escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode.ESCAPE, dialog );
```

Comment: I've tried the cleaner version ;) and I am getting no syntax error anymore but once the stage pops up in a matter of second it gets closed automatically and doesnt wait for me to click the escape button :D

Comment: As this question was about the problem with calling your function and this question was answered, I would propose to please ask another question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. the code for one of your images) where the actual functionality of your listener can be fixed :)